# get video fps using FFProbe

Tags: java, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I am new in ffprobe my aim is get video fps and store into java program. my code store xml files but i want store directly like int fps=30;

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format xml -show_format -show_streams "/video/small/small.avi" > "/video/small/test.xml"
```

this is my code.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This will print the video FPS:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate file.mp4
```

Comment: Yes, it prints the FPS, but only as a precise fraction. Fortunately, you can take this fraction and put it into a calculator to get a decimal value. For example, if the answer from this command is `30000/1001`, you can put that into a calculator which yields `29.97002997`, rounding up to approximately 30 FPS.

Comment: You can replace "-show_entries stream=r_frame_rate" with "-show_entries stream" to get a list of all available values, and use "-of json/flat/..." to get the data in a more parseable format if needed

Comment: I noticed that r_frame_rate can return misleading numbers! avg_frame_rate was much more correct.

Comment: To get the FPS statistics for all the videos in a folder, use `ls *.mp4 | xargs -n 1 -- ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate | sort | uniq -c`

Answer (score 5):

You can simply run this also, to get the video FPS, this will work on linux machines.

```
ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams -select_streams v:0 INPUT |grep "r_frame_rate"
```

Comment: No need for `grep`. Just use `ffprobe` by itself as shown in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer suggests using `stream=r_frame_rate`. This is okay if you only need a slightly rounded result. (30/1 instead of ~29.7)

### For a Precise & Unrounded FPS, Divide Total Frames by Duration:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -count_frames -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames -print_format csv="p=0" input.mp4 | read frames && 
ffprobe -i input.mp4 -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0" | read duration && 
echo $(($frames/$duration))
    >> 29.970094916135743
```

**Duration of file:**

```
ffprobe -i input.mp4 -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"
    >> 15.367000
```

**Total frame count of file:**

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -count_frames -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames -print_format csv input.mp4
    >> 461
```

Comment: Nice, but counting the frames is quite slow and expensive. And the duration returns "stream,<number of frames>", so we need to extract the "second column".

Comment: this gave an inaccurate answer for me

Comment: @danday74 how so? This divides total frames by total seconds to yield a precise, unrounded answer. What were your inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 1):

Get the video FPS and print it to stdout:
Saw the answer by @geo-freak and added it to get only the frame rate (remove the extra text).

```
ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams -select_streams v:0 input.mp4 |grep "r_frame_rate" | sed -e 's/r_frame_rate=//'
```

The answer by @o_ren seems more reasonable.

Python Function to do the same:

```
def get_video_frame_rate(filename):
result = subprocess.run(
    [
        "ffprobe",
        "-v",
        "error",
        "-select_streams",
        "v",
        "-of",
        "default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1",
        "-show_entries",
        "stream=r_frame_rate",
        filename,
    ],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
)
result_string = result.stdout.decode('utf-8').split()[0].split('/')
fps = float(result_string[0])/float(result_string[1])
return fps
```

Answer (score 0):

I found calculate fps in another method that is..

```
String query = "ffmpeg -i foo.avi 2>&1 | sed -n 's/.*, \\(.*\\) fp.*/\\1/p' > fps.txt";
    String[] command = {"gnome-terminal", "-x", "/bin/sh", "-c", query};
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    process.waitFor();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("fps.txt")));
        output = br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Anyway thanks friends.