# I m trying to use 'ffprobe' with Java or groovy

Tags: json, grails, groovy, ffprobe

As per my understanding "ffprobe" will provide file related data in JSON format. So, I have installed the ffprobe in my Ubuntu machine but I don't know how to access the ffprobe JSON response using Java/Grails.

Expected response format:

```
{
    "format": {
        "filename": "/Users/karthick/Documents/videos/TestVideos/sample.ts",
        "nb_streams": 2,
        "nb_programs": 1,
        "format_name": "mpegts",
        "format_long_name": "MPEG-TS (MPEG-2 Transport Stream)",
        "start_time": "1.430800",
        "duration": "170.097489",
        "size": "80425836",
        "bit_rate": "3782576",
        "probe_score": 100
    }
}
```

This is my groovy code

```
 def process = "ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams HelloWorld.mpeg ".execute()             
        println "Found ${process.text}"
        render  process  as JSON
```

I m able to get the process object and i m not able to get the json response

Should i want to convert the process object to json object?

OUTPUT:

Found java.lang.UNIXProcess@75566697
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException: Error converting Bean with class java.lang.UNIXProcess

Comment: This isn't a service to write code to meet your specification. What have _you_ tried? Take a look at [get video fps using ffprobe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27792934/get-video-fps-using-ffprobe) or http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#execute()

Answer (score 1):

> Groovy provides a simple way to execute command line processes. Simply
>   write the command line as a string and call the `execute()` method.
>
> The execute() method returns a `java.lang.Process` instance.

```
println "ffprobe <options>".execute().text
```

[[Source]](http://www.groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#process-management)

Comment: Now i m able to use ffprobe now i used this command " ffprobe -show_format -loglevel quiet " and i got response in output which looks like                                                                          [FORMAT]
filename=HelloWorld.mpeg
nb_streams=2
format_name=mpeg
format_long_name=MPEG-PS format
start_time=0.768300 
duration=20.966667 
size=706564.000000 
  
[/FORMAT]
but i cant able to access those values and if i need to use that i want them in json format and so i used this command "ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams HelloWorld.mpeg "

Comment: But this command  "ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams HelloWorld.mpeg " is not working, i m getting process object, but not able to get json .

Comment: use the absolute path for both the media file and ffprobe if it's not in PATH

Comment: No change this is my CODE : 
def process = "ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams /home/karthikv/workspace/Mpeg/HelloWorld.mpeg".execute()             
   println "Found ${process}"
   render  process  as JSON  
OUTPUT : 
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException: Error converting Bean with class java.lang.UNIXProcess .
Not able to get json

Answer (score 0):

Grails has nothing to do with this. Groovy can execute arbitrary shell commands in a very simplistic way:

```
"mkdir foo".execute()
```

Or for more advanced features, you might look into using [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). At the end of the day, you need to execute ffprobe and then capture the output stream of JSON to use in your app.

Comment: i dont know how to capture the output stream of JSON in groovy,what i did is with the process object i rendered as JSON but it is returning this error:
 " org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException: Error converting Bean with class java.lang.UNIXProcess "